# What does 與 mean in 對我來說她的存在是與現實之間的邊界綫?

Tags: mandarin, meaning-in-context, word

I was curious about this sentence:

> 對我來說她的存在是與現實之間的邊界綫

I don't quite understand the meaning of 與

The dictionary I use gives the following definitions:

> - 與  yú variant of 歟|欤
> - 與  yǔ and; to give; together with
> - 與  yù to take part in

I think it is using the fourth tone, meaning "to take part in"

My interpretation of the sentence is:

> As for me, her existence 'takes part' between the borderline of
>   reality (and non reality)

Unfortunately this sounds a bit weird and I'm worrying that it's completely wrong.

If anyone could shed some light on the issue I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

對我來說 - to me,

她的存在 - her existence

是 - is

???? (object A - *missing* )

**與 - and**

現實 reality (object B)

之間的 - that between

邊界綫 - the borderline

> [1. 對我來說] [2. 她的存在] [3. 是] [4. X] [5. 與] [6.現實][7. 之間的] [8. 邊界綫]
>
> [1. to me] [2. her existence] [3. is] [4. X][5.and] [6. reality][7. between] [8. the borderline] (*Chinese grammar*)
>
> [1. to me] [2. her existence] [3. is] [8.the borderline] [7. between] [4. X] [5. and] [6. reality]  (*English grammar*)

*X could be something opposite of reality , e.g. "dream", "fantasy"*

"Her existence is the borderline between dream **and** reality"

X could also be 'I' meaning if she didn't exist, I would have to face reality

Answer (score 1):

對我來說她的存在是與現實之間的邊界綫

Normally 之間 translates as 'between'. The logic of 'between' requires 2 objects for a third object to be located 'between' them. The logic of 現實之間 escapes me!

對我來說，她的存在是虚拟（虚幻）与（和）現實之間的邊界綫。
As far as I am concerned, her existence is on the borderline between the illusory and reality.

You are trying to say she's a shady lady??